# How do I update a live website?

Tags: page-refresh

I updated my website with new links.  The website is live.

How do I get the public to see the updates? Can I make the pages update themselves automatically. Right now, unless they refresh the webpage, they won't know the updates.

Comment: Why wouldn't they refresh the pages?  Do they just sit there and stare at an unmoving browser all day long?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest thing you can do is set a meta refresh in your page's header, which would suggest to the client browsers to reload your page after a fixed interval:

```
<html>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="100" />
</head>
etc...
```

which would make the page reload after 100 seconds. There's various other tricks you could do with Javascript, AJAX polling, etc... But this is basically universally supported.

Answer (score 0):

they will have to reload the web page for any updated content to show. If thi is somethig you do very often, and your visitors do not reload your page at a high enough frequency, you may want to look at either using [META REFRESH](http://webdesign.about.com/od/metataglibraries/a/aa080300a.htm) or  using AJAX to reload the content on a regular timed basis see [this quick tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/Ajax/Default.Asp)